# Unitils/DBunit and database test

Tags: java, unit-testing, dbunit, unitils

I want to try to make unit test with DBUnit but I have a problem with my dataset.

Here is my persistence object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personnes")
public class Personne implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer pk;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

And my dataset:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <personnes name="toto"  pk="1" />
</dataset>
```

My problem is with the name column, I get this error:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: personnes.NAME -  (Non-uppercase input column: name) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
```

I don't understand why dbunit search a column "NAME" whereas my column is "name".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Your issue may have to do with this bug, which has apparently been around for quite sometime... https://unitils.atlassian.net/browse/UNI-134

Answer (score 4):

I've been fighting this for a while, and keep coming back to this issue, which doesn't seem to have a solution yet.

In Unitils 3.4.1, they added a new property, `org.dbunit.database.IMetadataHandler.implClassName`

In my unitils.properties file, I added the following line

```
org.dbunit.database.IMetadataHandler.implClassName=org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlMetadataHandler
```

Yes, I know, according to Unitils' website, there is no version 3.4.1, but you can get the latest version via Maven.

[link to issue report](https://unitils.atlassian.net/browse/UNI-152)

Comment: this answer should be accepted since it's the only one that makes sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the column name in the mapping, I guess the underlying ORM framework generates the column name "NAME" for it.

To resolve this error/warning, you could add the column name to the mapping

```
@Column( name = "name")
```

resulting in a lower-case column name or use upper-case notation in your dataset

```
<personnes NAME="toto"  pk="1" />
```

leaving the upper-case column name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following to true

```
DatabaseConfig.FEATURE_CASE_SENSITIVE_TABLE_NAMES
```

within your `DatabaseConfig` object.

See [org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: Did not find table 'xxx' in schema 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066201/org-dbunit-dataset-nosuchtableexception-did-not-find-table-xxx-in-schema-nul)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set datatype factory for your databases.

All available factories can be found on this link. http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/datatype/IDataTypeFactory.html

Choose factory which belongs to your database.

Implement method setUpDatabaseConfig in your test class and set factory.

```
protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {
   config.setProperty( DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new OracleDataTypeFactory() );
}
```